# Why am I getting an Array out of bounds error?

Tags: java

I can not figure out why my code won't let me remove a value from my list. I am suppose to make the list have 10 values in it, and then when I want to take a value out and replace it I use remove() and then add(). My error says this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 9 
     at MyList.remove(MyList.java:36) 
     at MyListDriver.main(MyListDriver.java:17)
```

Here is my code for those sections:

```
public class MyListDriver{
public static void main(String[] args){


MyList alpha = new MyList(9);
alpha.add("22");


alpha.add("2");
alpha.add("1");
alpha.add("22");
alpha.add("13");      
alpha.add("6");   
alpha.add("7");
alpha.add("32");
alpha.add("172");
alpha.add("2");
alpha.remove("12");
alpha.add("23");
alpha.print();
}
}
```

And the section from the MyList that is the remove(), which is where I am getting an error.

```
public void remove(String data){
  int index = 0;
  for(int r = 0; r <=arr.length; r++)
  {
      if(arr[r].equals(data)){
         index=r;
         break;
      }
  }

  remove(index);
}
public void remove(int index){
      if(index>=0 && index<loc){
         for(int i=index; i<loc-1; i++){
            arr[index]=arr[index+1];
         }
         loc--;
      }
   }
```

I am suppose to have an overloaded remove method. I dont know why I am getting an Array out of bounds error.

Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: change to `for(int r = 0; r <arr.length; r++)`

Comment: Thank you, silly error but quite frustrating. I really appreciate it :)

Comment: @ScaryWombat right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I know U got The Answer**

```
for(int r = 0; r <=arr.length; r++)
  {
      if(arr[r].equals(data)){
         index=r;
         break;
      }
  }
```

**why u getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`**

because of when r=arr.lenght for Ex. array lenght is 3 means `0 1 2`

when r=3 the condition retunrn true because 3<=3 so change it

```
for(int r = 0; r < arr.length; r++)
  {
      if(arr[r].equals(data)){
         index=r;
         break;
      }
  }
```